# stack get 8 byte more than its need

Tags: assembly, stack, buffer-overflow

I write very simple program in c as below:

```
include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
char buffer[80];
getchar();
strcpy(buffer,argv[1]);
return 1;
}
```

when I disassemble that ,It looks like below:

```
0x08048414 <+0>:    push   %ebp
   0x08048415 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048417 <+3>: sub    $0x58,%esp
   0x0804841a <+6>: call   0x8048320 <getchar@plt>
   0x0804841f <+11>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048422 <+14>:    add    $0x4,%eax
   0x08048425 <+17>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
   0x08048427 <+19>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
   0x0804842b <+23>:    lea    -0x50(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804842e <+26>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048431 <+29>:    call   0x8048330 <strcpy@plt>
   0x08048436 <+34>:    mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x0804843b <+39>:    leave  
   0x0804843c <+40>:    ret
```

My question is why it sub $0x58 from %esp, Not $0x50?
I run program with 80 "A" as argument
And this is result of stack after strcpy(buffer,argv[1]);

```
x/24xw $esp

    0xbffff290: 0xbffff298  0xbffff51e  0x41414141  0x41414141
    0xbffff2a0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
    0xbffff2b0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
    0xbffff2c0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
    0xbffff2d0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
    0xbffff2e0: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x00000000  0xb7e3f4d3
```

Comment: Because `buffer` isn't the only thing that needs to go on the stack frame.

Comment: Stack alignment - need to maintain 16 byte alignment: 4 bytes return address + 4 bytes ebp + 0x58 bytes = 0x60 bytes.

Comment: Address 0xbffff2ec point to return address. but whats the two word at first(0xbffff298  0xbffff51e)?

Comment: The two arguments to `strcpy` that is `buffer` and `argv[1]` placed on the stack at lines `+19` and `+26`.

Comment: Not to mention that strcpy() to a stack variable is most of the time a warm welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra 8 bytes are for the parameters to `strcpy`.  For some reason your compiler chooses to preallocate them on the stack, and directly store their values using `esp` as an index register, instead of using `push` instructions which is the way it is usually done.

So, the compiler could have allocated only 80 bytes on the stack if the instruction `mov %eax,0x4(%esp)` was replaced with `push %eax` and the instruction `mov %eax,(%esp)` was also replaced with `push %eax`.

Comment: One other detail, if you use the two `push`'s then you probably would also want to pop those values on return (be it with an `add $8, %esp`) otherwise your stack is off. Hence, this is an optimization which helps make programs smaller and overall faster.

Comment: Yes, though one little detail on the detail, the values would only have to be popped if they were being pushed in a loop.  When there are no calls In loops, (as the case is with the code in this question,) the stack being off does not really matter, because of the `leave` instruction.